# Наказанье = наказ?

Tags: орфография

Правда, что слово *наказанье* — в отличие от *наказание* — можно употреблять в значении 'наказ, просьба'?

> Его предсмертное **наказанье** было таково: «Не продавайте же мой дачный дом».

Comment: Лео, отличный вопрос, попробуй заглянуть с ним на Interpreting Dreams SE.